# Scroll with anchor without # in URL

Tags: javascript, html, hash

I need to scroll through a page using `anchor tag`.

Right now I'm doing:

```
<a href="#div1">Link1</a>

<div id='div1'>link1 points me!!</div>
```

This works fine when I clicked on Link1, the page scrolls to the div with id "div1".
The point is, I do not want to change my URL which takes `#div` as suffix once I clicked on `Link1`.

I tried with anchor href as

```
void(0);
```

and

```
location.hash='#div1';
return false;

e.preventdefault;
```

How to avoid changing the URL?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Take this answer from Jeff Hines using jQuery's animate:

```
function goToByScroll(id){
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top},'slow');
}
```

If you're using jQuery don't forget to add the library to your project.

Edit: Also, make sure that you still "return false;" in the click handler for the link, otherwise it'll still add the "#div1" to your URL (thanks @niaccurshi)

Comment: Also, make sure that you still "return false" in the click handler for the link, otherwise it'll still add the "#div1" to your URL

Comment: This works well.  Spent a bunch of time on the old # anchor tags but they seem to get 'broken' when there is a bunch of scripting.

Answer (score 51):

`scrollIntoView` did the best job when all other methods failed!

```
document.getElementById('top').scrollIntoView(true);
```

Where `'top'` is the id of the html tag you want to go.

Comment: Thanks a lot dear!

Comment: Upvote even though this didn't work for me for some reason last time I tried.

Comment: This is a better solution than the accepted one because when I used the accepted one, it doesn't take into account any margins above or below the position being scrolled to. As a result, part of the text is cut off when the scrolling is done.

Comment: Though I like this answer, it fails to also bring focus to where you scroll. For example if you have a "Skip to main content" link for accessible users and you want to scroll to the main content, using this will not move the focus to the main content area.

Comment: ```scrollIntoViewOptions``` don't work in Safari though.

Answer (score 9):

Make your life easier, try the following and let me know if there is anything else ;-)

```
<div>top</div>
<div style="height: 800px;">&nbsp;</div>
<div><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="window.scroll(0,1);">click here</a></div>
```

**FYI:** You only need to play around with one/single line `href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="window.scroll(0,1);"` and it works for you.

Have a good day!

Answer (score 5):

Only Add this code into jquery on document ready

Ref : http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^/ / , '') == this.pathname.replace(/^/ / , '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Add smooth scroll to any item click including anchor, button etc without adding div id to URL :)

***Info:***
 **scrollIntoViewOptions(Optional)**
    {
      behavior: "auto"  | "instant" | "smooth",
      block:    "start" | "end",
    }

```js
function scrollSmoothTo(elementId) {
  var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
  element.scrollIntoView({
    block: 'start',
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
}
```

```css
#userdiv {
  margin-top: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="scrollSmoothTo('userdiv')">
  Scroll to userdiv
</button>

<div id="userdiv">
  Lorem ipsum this is a random text
</div>
```

[DEMO](https://codepen.io/ProgrammingDIY/pen/XBvQQq)

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

Answer (score 1):

Riffing off [Henser's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15223074/3425496), I have a case where the `window.location.hash` is already set, and the user then scrolls back to the top of the page (where the hash link is).

Since the hash is already set, you can re-locate on clicking that link by:

```
$(window).scrollTop($('a[name='+id+']').offset().top);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm know I'm 4 years late, but you guys can try this.

HTML:

```
<a href="#div1">Link1</a>
<!-- you can put <br />'s here to see effect -->
<div id='div1'>link1 points me!!</div>
<!-- <br />'s here, too, to see effect -->
```

JavaScript/jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var hash = this.hash;
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top}, 900);
    });
})
```

Comment: This is really bad. As written when you click **ANY** anchor tag, you will initialize this function. You should target a specific ID. Also, your solution does not work.

Comment: it works well you just need to define the class instead of universal "a" tag

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('top').scrollIntoView(true);
```

should work for all browser, tested!