# Remove " #'something' " from url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a website with only one page. In nav bar, there are a links which leads to certain part of page. I'm using this code to help me with smooth scrolling and changing active a tag in nav bar:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);

    // smoothscroll
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(document).off("scroll");

        $('a').each(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        })
        $(this).addClass('active');

        var target = this.hash,
            menu = target;
        $target = $(target);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top+2
        }, 800, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
            $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
        });
    });
});

function onScroll(event){
    var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
    $('#nav-bar a').each(function () {
        var currLink = $(this);
        var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
        if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
            $('#nav #nav-bar ul li a').removeClass("active");
            currLink.addClass("active");
        }
        else{
            currLink.removeClass("active");
        }
    });
}
```

Everything work fine. But I have one problem. If you click on one page from nav bar, for example "About us", in url appears "/#about" from anchor id.

I would like to remove it, because I have only one page and it doesn't looks good.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scroll with anchor without # in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15223006/scroll-with-anchor-without-in-url)

Comment: Thanks, but that still didn't help me.