# Re-directing without change in url

Tags: reactjs, anchor

Anchor Tag without change of URL

I have a multistep form which is working as per my expectation.

Now I have a side nav bar  in which all the components of the form are listed. I want to make them clickable and it should re-direct to the part of the form clicked without the change in url. How can I acheive this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15223006/scroll-with-anchor-without-in-url

Comment: should we need to re-render the master component or just scroll to the corresponding component?

Comment: I need to load the corresponding component on click