# Don't want to add anchor href to the url when scroll button clicked

Tags: javascript, css, scroll

I am building a single-page website, it will have a landing page and a main page where the user will do some computation. In the landing page, there is a button for scrolling smoothly to the main page. While I was researching how to make this scrolling stuff, I've found that CSS property called `scroll-behaviour` used with anchors.

What I don't like about this approach is when I clicked the anchor button, the id of the scrolled div is appended to the URL. See below snipped:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

#landing-page {
    background-color: bisque;
    height: 100vh;
}

#main-page {
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="landing-page">
        <h1>Landing Page</h1>
        <a href="#main-page">Go to main page</a>
    </div>
    <div id="main-page">
        <h1>Main Page</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I clicked the button, it scrolls to the correct viewport but URL becomes `localhost:1234/#main-page` from `localhost:1234`. As may it sounds unnecessary concern, I really want to prevent this. Is there anything I can do, or maybe should I change the scrolling approach altogether(not using anchors)?

Comment: What you are describing has nothing to do with `scroll-behavior`. You are simply using named anchors and named anchors take you to a named portion of the document. The change in the URL is not something you can avoid. If you want this behavior and no change to the URL, you'll need to implement the scrolling behavior with JavaScript.

Comment: @ScottMarcus, so is there any other way to achieve this smooth scrolling other than using anchors.

Comment: Yes, as I said, through the use of a JavaScript implementation.

Comment: See this post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15223006/scroll-with-anchor-without-in-url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you don't want the URL to change, you have to scroll to the element using javascript. Something like:

```js
document.getElementById("anchorElement").addEventListener("click", e => {
    document.getElementById("main-page").scrollIntoView();
})
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

#anchorElement {
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#landing-page {
    background-color: bisque;
    height: 100vh;
}

#main-page {
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="landing-page">
        <h1>Landing Page</h1>
        <span id="anchorElement">Go to main page</span>
    </div>
    <div id="main-page">
        <h1>Main Page</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```